If SHA256 is successfully attacked, will we need to replace the hash function and re-timestamp the entire blockchain from the beginning?

If SHA256 is successfully attacked, what measures will be taken to replace the compromised hash function?

In the event of a SHA256 attack, will it be necessary to re-timestamp the entire blockchain from the beginning?

What are the potential challenges and implications of switching to a new hash function in the blockchain?



This question is similar to: If SHA256 and/or RIPEMD-160 were broken, would all bitcoin addresses be compromised?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There was a similar question to this on the BitcoinTalk forum in 2010, to which Satoshi Nakamoto contributed:

SHA-256 is very strong.  It's not like the incremental step from MD5
to SHA1.  It can last several decades unless there's some massive
breakthrough attack.
If SHA-256 became completely broken, I think we could come to some
agreement about what the honest block chain was before the trouble
started, lock that in and continue from there with a new hash
function.
If the hash breakdown came gradually, we could transition to a new
hash in an orderly way.  The software would be programmed to start
using a new hash after a certain block number.  Everyone would have to
upgrade by that time.  The software could save the new hash of all the
old blocks to make sure a different block with the same old hash can't
be used.

